# How to run python script in docker with the script being sent dynamically to docker container?

Tags: python, docker

How to run python script in docker with the script being sent dynamically to docker container ?

Also, it should handle multiple simultaneous connections. For example, if two run is executed by two people at once, it should not override the file created by one person by the another.

Comment: I forgot saying, its Ubuntu image

Answer (score 4):

Normally, you [Mount a host file as a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-file-as-a-data-volume), or, in your case, a [host directory](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume).
See the [python image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/):

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python:3 python your-daemon-or-script.py
```

That way, if a file is created in that mounted folder, it will be created on the host hard-drive, and won't be overridden by another user executing the same script in his/her own container.

---

For an Ubutu image, you need

- an initial copy of the Git repo, cloned as a bare repo (`git clone --mirror`).
- an Apache installed, listening for Git request

When you fetch a PR, you can run a new container, and push that PR branch to the container Git repo. A post-receive hook on that container repo can trigger a python script.
- then you can

Comment: @user1305989 OK, I have edited the answer with an alternative approach, including a one-container per Pull-Request, which would achieve complete isolation from host.